# Class with general and specialized attributes

Tags: c++, design-patterns, configuration

How to model a class with general and specific attributes based on type. For example I have a Primitive class. The Primitive class has the following general members : PrimitiveType, translation, rotation, plus additional fields based on the primitive type.

```
enum PrimitiveType
{
   CYLYNDER,
   CUBE,
   CONE
}
class Primitive
{
   string name;
   PrimitiveType type;
   double positionX,positionY,positionZ;
   double rotationX,rotationY,rotationZ;

  // following members are if primitivetype is CYLYNDER
   double height;
   double radius;

  //following members are if primitive is CUBE
  double height;
  double width;
  double length;

};
```

I can of course do inheritance and make Primitive and Cylynder and Cube classes that inherit from Primitive. But classes have not polymorphic relationships between themselves, so I do not to use inheritance. I need them as just plain structures that hold attributes.

I can make also composition and make Cylynder and Cube classes that have Primitive member. But I need to store objects of Cylynder,Cube and Cone in one vector. So if I do composition how I will store them in one std::vector .

I basically need to model the structures in a such way that I need to met the following requirements :

1) store objects of the different types of components in one std::vector

2) store object of different types in a easy readable and editable config file.
   In the config file I want to save only the specialized attributes that are relevant for the specific type of the primitive, and not the specialized attributes for all primitive types.
   So I want to get something like this in the config file :

```
<Primitive>
 <name>Primitive1</name>
 <type>CYLYNDER</type>
 <positionx>0</positionx>
 <!-- other common attributes here, omitted to save space -->

 <!-- specific primitive type attributes -->
 <height> 10 </height>
 <redius>5</radius>
</Primitive>
<Primitive>
  <name> Primitive2 </name>
  <type> CUBE </type>
  <positionx>0</positionx>
  <!-- other common attributes here, omitted to save space -->

  <!-- specific primitive type attributes -->
  <height>10</height>
  <width>10</width>
  <length>10</length>
</Primitive>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many choices, e.g.:

- create three distinct classes and store `boost::variant<Cylinder, Cube, Cone>`s in the `vector` (conceptually that's a discriminated union, but `boost::variant` cleans it up for you and handles the ugly edge cases like alignment)

  - you can still use composition for the shared members/functionality if desired
- create one class with an enum and a "fat" interface and fields (as you've started to do above, but removing the duplicate for height into a "// for many primitives" group)

  - hackish and entangled, but if you don't have too many PrimitiveTypes to deal with, and they're not too complex, this may be manageable and practical
- use polymorphism - it certainly seems like there'll be some common subset of functionality that can be exposed, and while it's ugly `dynamic_cast<>` supports runtime-type-specific switching

  - your *"have not polymorphic relationships between themselves, so I do not to use inheritance"* isn't a compelling justification for avoiding it, given your claimed need to store the types in a single `vector`

As for creating the objects from the file content... what you need is called a "factory" - it can read the PrimitiveType from the config file then call type-specific field-parsing and finally construction code.

Comment: Depending on how the design will be used, the polymorphic solution could have a drawback with respect to the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Personally, I think the first one is safer, especially with `boost::variant`

Answer (score 0):

This may be overkill for your case, but I'm used to dealing with these kinds of problems in proprietary APIs that could not afford to use the likes of `boost::variant` to avoid the public dependency (requiring plugin writers to have boost installed) and to allow the variant type to extend the range of supported types at pseudo-runtime (ex: from a dylib plugin that is loaded in the middle of the application). It's helpful to have a general building block to turn non-homogenous types into something homogeneous, capable of being stored in a single container, accessed uniformly, etc.

When you want those kinds of runtime property systems and reflection and some level of homogeneity between types, the statically-typed nature of C++ can make it a bit difficult. The language doesn't give you the means to do these types of things necessarily off the bat. It's especially tricky if you have tight ABI restrictions.

If you're interested in this kind of roll-up-your-sleeves proprietary solution, the first building block is a poor man's RTTI that works across module boundaries:

```
// Implemented at a central core level.
int to_type_code(const char* type_name);

// Registers a new type with the system.
// Thread safety omitted here for the sake of simplicity.
#define REGISTER_TYPE(type) \
    template <> inline \
    int type_code<type>() \
    { \
        static const int val = to_type_code(#type); \
        return val; \
    }

// Example usage:
REGISTER_TYPE(bool);
REGISTER_TYPE(char);
REGISTER_TYPE(short);
REGISTER_TYPE(int);
// etc
```

Now you can do things like `type_code<int>()` from any module and get the same result. This gives us something on which we can map type-specific functionality, like what GUI control/widget to show when the system encounters a given type (to allow you to generate GUIs automatically from the data, especially handy when combined with reflection),  what functionality is required to serialize that type, clone it, create it, destroy it, convert it to another type, etc. -- whatever you want.

The next step is a way to store that type generically through a homogeneous type, similar to `boost::variant`. Simplified (omitting `const` methods, e.g.) example you can build upon:

```
class Variant
{
public:
    virtual ~Variant() {}

    virtual int type() const = 0;
    virtual void* data() = 0;

    // Can/should use a smart pointer here (for ABI, make sure it captures
    // destruction at the call site).
    virtual Variant* clone() const = 0;

    template <class T>
    T& get()
    {
        assert(type_code<T>() != -1 && "Type is unknown!");
        assert(type() == type_code<T>() && "Mismatching types!");
        return static_cast<T*>(data());
    }

    template <class T>
    Variant& operator=(const T& new_val)
    {
        assert(type_code<T>() != -1 && "Type is unknown!");
        assert(type() == type_code<T>() && "Mismatching types!");
        *static_cast<T*>(data()) = new_val;
    }

    // ...
};

template <class T>
class VariantT: public Variant
{
public:
    explicit VariantT(const T& ival): val(ival), code(type_code<T>()) 
    {
        assert(code != -1 && "Type is unknown!");
    }
    virtual VariantT* clone() const override {return new VariantT(*this);}
    virtual int type() const override {return type_code<T>();}
    virtual void* data() override {return &val;}

private:
    T val;
};
```

Now you can store your primitive types and even the fields inside VariantT, its height in VariantT, etc., and they can all be referenced through `Variant*`. Example:

```
VariantT<double> var_double(1.5);
Variant& var = var_double;
double my_double = var.get<double>(); // --> 1.5
int my_int = var.get<int>(); // assertion failure -- type mismatch.
unique_ptr<Variant> clone(var.clone()); // make a copy
```

There's some `vptr` overhead here, but if you need this kind of extensible property design, it requires considerably less effort than applying these abstractions only at the aggregate object level. If you need more safety, you can also turn those debug-only assertions into exception or error handlers with runtime branching if you can pay afford the cycles. Using this, you can provide objects that have reflection (listing variants available), store their properties uniformly through Variant*, map serializers to the appropriate type codes and uniformly serialize whole objects of just specific attributes/properties, etc.